# Sharing a document and other document management

Tags: google-apps-script

I am doing some document management in GAS. Have traversed the documentation carefully but not found any answers for the following (to be done by my script, not manually). Anyone who knows?

- How do I share a document with another user?
- I noticed that DocumentApp.create() creates and opens a document, but is there any way to supress the opening (just do the create)?
- Is it possible to create a document from a template?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a basic answer, all three of your needs are possible within primary methods of the `DocsList` Service.

1. Sharing a document = [File[].addViewer()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addViewer) or [File[].addEditor()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#addEditor)
2. Creating a document in Apps Script only opens it in memory, not as a browser tab
3. Creating from a template is simply copying a file (the template) and renaming / editing the content. [File[].makeCopy()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_file#makeCopy)

There will no doubt be umpteen follow-up nuanced answers that might be given, but you'd need to start with a use-case description or what an example of what you have already tried.

[Tutorial: Interacting With Your Docs List](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/docslist_tutorial) makes for a good introduction.